# Stack / concatenate rasters in a list (terra - spatRaster)

Tags: r, terra

I want to stack a few rasters I have in a list using terra.

This used to work very easily in raster because it was possible to `stack()` the list.
However, this is not possible anymore in terra.
See the example below:

```
r1 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.1)
r2 <- raster(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, res = 0.5, xmn = -1.5, xmx = 1.5, ymn = -1.5, ymx = 1.5, vals = 0.2)
r_list <- list(r1, r2)
r_stack <- stack(r_list)
```

Resuls in a raster stack:

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 6, 6, 36, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : -1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : layer.1, layer.2 
min values :     0.1,     0.2 
max values :     0.1,     0.2
```

But the equivalent in terra, using `c()`, does not work directly on the list:

```
r1 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.1)
r2 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.2)
r_list <- list(r1, r2)
r_c <- c(r_list)
```

The error is this:

> Error in .local(x, ...) :
> Arguments should be Raster* objects or filenames

Is there a workaround to stack spatRaster in a list?

Comment: Some typo is there. The second r1 should be r2. Use `r_c <- c(r1, r2)` and delete `r_list <- list(r1, r2)`. `r_list <- list(r1, r2)` is also not required in `raster` package. Directly you can run `r_stack <- stack(r1, r2)`

Comment: corrected - thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code to convert the list to a stacked raster using `terra` package

```
library(terra)

r1 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.1)
r2 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.2)
r_list <- list(r1, r2)
r_c <- rast(r_list)
```

which gives you

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 6, 6, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : -1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
sources     : memory  
              memory  
names       : lyr.1, lyr.1 
min values  :   0.1,   0.2 
max values  :   0.1,   0.2
```

Or you can use the following

```
r1 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.1)
r2 <- rast(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, resolution = 0.5, xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5, vals = 0.2)

r_c <- c(r1, r2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very straight forward